# How do I prevent "document.referrer" not to contain the value of a signing call back, but to read the parent URl after the call back

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, iframe

I have a page with an iframe and i use document.referrer to obtain the parent url.
But users have to signing to Microsoft online first, then the page loads.Here is a snippet of my code.

```js
var isInIframe = (parent !== window);
if (isInIframe) {
  parentRawUrl = document.referrer;
} else {
  parentRawUrl = window.top.location.href;
}
```

The referrer value contains the url of the signing page,I have to refresh the page to get the correct value or the parent url.

How do I force the referrer value not to take the signing url, but only the parent url which contains the iframe.